# HTTP Status 404 on First Spring MVC Project

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

for several days I'm trying run my First application in Spring MVC , I start this project on spring tool suits with pivotal server.

Project i rewrite from Spring in Action book . Ecipse run it automatically on link http://localhost:8081/Splittr/. Maybe someone see any error in this project.

Project looks like this

```
-src
 -main
  -spittr
     -config
      RootConfig.java
      SpittrWebAppInitializer.java
      WebConfig.java
     -web
      HomeController.java
   -webapp
        -WEB-INF
         -views
           home.jsp
```

SpittrWebAppInitializer.java

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings(){
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses(){
        return new Class<?>[] {RootConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses(){
        return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};
    }

}
```

RootConfig.java

```
package spittr.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"spittr"},
excludeFilters ={
        @Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class)
})
public class RootConfig {

}
```

WebConfig

```
package spittr.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spittr.web") =
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =
                new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

HomeController

```
package spittr.web;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method =GET)
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }

}
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Spittr</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css"
href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" >
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welocme in  Spittr</h1>
<a href="<c:url value="/spittles" />">Spittle</a> |
<a href="<c:url value="/spitter/register" />">Register</a>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.spitttr.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>Splittr</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Splittr Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Splittr</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you added the folder containing web pages to the classpath and deployment assembly?

Comment: I build project by maven , but i don't really known it is enough. In deployment assembly in properties for project i have source with line src/main/webapp

Comment: Is the web page in src/main/webapp? Also, if you are running in apache server, check run configurations. Right Click Project> Run > Run Configurations. Click Arguments tab. There is a block called Working directory. This is where the workspace is specified. If your project is in default workspace the value in default is default is fine. Else, click other and select workspace that your project is present in.

Comment: Yes , home.jsp is in src/main/webapp, working directory is point to default directory I use pivotal server

Comment: first try to just run http://localhost:8081/ if still not ok please share your pom.xml and your web.xml.

Comment: localhost working fine, i didint have web.xml because i hava configuration by java adnotation andI share pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please to try `@ComponentScan("spittr.*")` on your RootConfig.java